# Alembic - Attempting to autogenerate revision throws "sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:postgresql.psycopg"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

Edit: The outputs below were run on Windows with Git bash.

---

I am new to Alembic and SQLAlchemy.

I have been tasked with adding Alembic support to an existing FastAPI + SQLAlchemy application. To this end, I have done some preliminary setup by calling `alembic init` and updated the `alembic.ini` and `env.py` files.

Then I tried to call `alembic revision --autogenerate -m "Initial revision"` but Alembic throws this error:

```
$ alembic revision --autogenerate -m "Initial revision"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desmond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\Desmond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Desmond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\alembic.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Desmond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\alembic\config.py", line 632, in main
    CommandLine(prog=prog).main(argv=argv)
  File "C:\Users\Desmond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\alembic\config.py", line 626, in main
    self.run_cmd(cfg, options)
  File "C:\Users\Desmond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\alembic\config.py", line 603, in run_cmd
    fn(
  File "C:\Users\Desmond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\alembic\command.py", line 236, in revision
    script_directory.run_env()
  File "C:\Users\Desmond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\alembic\script\base.py", line 582, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, "env.py")
  File "C:\Users\Desmond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\alembic\util\pyfiles.py", line 94, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
  File "C:\Users\Desmond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\alembic\util\pyfiles.py", line 110, in load_module_py
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)  # type: ignore
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Desmond\Projects\application-git\extraction_accuracy\api\accuracy\alembic\env.py", line 8, in <module>
    from database.session import DatabaseModelBase
  File "C:\Users\Desmond\Projects\application-git\extraction_accuracy\api\accuracy\.\database\session.py", line 8, in <module>
    engine = create_engine(
  File "<string>", line 2, in create_engine
  File "C:\Users\Desmond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\deprecations.py", line 309, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Desmond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 534, in create_engine
    entrypoint = u._get_entrypoint()
  File "C:\Users\Desmond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\url.py", line 655, in _get_entrypoint
    cls = registry.load(name)
  File "C:\Users\Desmond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 343, in load
    raise exc.NoSuchModuleError(
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:postgresql.psycopg
```

I have checked and I have psycopg installed in my global packages:

```
$ pip list | grep psyco
psycopg                         3.1.12
psycopg-binary                  3.1.12
```

I have also updated the relevant details in the alembic.ini and env.py files:

alembic.ini:

```
sqlalchemy.url = postgresql://%(USERNAME)s:%(PASSWORD)s@%(HOST)s:%(PORT)s/%(DB_NAME)s
```

env.py (environment variables have been created in the current shell as well):

```
config = context.config

section = config.config_ini_section
config.set_section_option(
    section, "HOST", os.environ.get("DATABASE_HOST")
)
config.set_section_option(
    section, "PORT", os.environ.get("DATABASE_PORT")
)
config.set_section_option(
    section, "DB_NAME", os.environ.get("DATABASE_NAME")
)
config.set_section_option(
    section, "USERNAME", os.environ.get("USERNAME")
)
config.set_section_option(
    section, "PASSWORD", os.environ.get("PASSWORD")
)
target_metadata = DatabaseModelBase.metadata
```

The DatabaseModelBase in the stack trace is an instance of declarative_model() in session.py.

Please help.

Comment: What version of SQLAlchemy do you have installed? `psycopg` is only supported in 2.0+

Comment: I see that SQLAlchemy isn't explicitly defined in the requirements.txt file. I see these:
```
fastapi==0.94.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
intervals==0.9.2
psycopg[binary]==3.1.8
SQLAlchemy-Utils==0.40.0
uvicorn==0.21.1
```
Perhaps SQLAlchemy is an internal dependency of one of these packages?

Comment: No doubt; try `pip list` in your terminal and look for SQLAlchemy in the output.

Comment: I see. It's 1.4.39. This dependency was already there when I started working on this project. What would be the solution for versions below 2.0?

Comment: `psycopg is only supported in 2.0+` 

Aren't you thinking of psycopg2?

Comment: No `psycopg` is the successor project to `psycopg2`.  In terms of solutions, you could switch to `psycopg2`, but that might break things if for example your project is using async database connections. Or you could switch to `ayncpg` (or maybe pg8000, I can't remember if it supports async), but could be a problem if sync connections are required.

Comment: Ok, I switched to SQLAlchemy 2.0.12 and psycopg2-binary 2.9.6 and now Alembic is working. However, I will have to check and see if it breaks anything in the main app.

Comment: Well, now the main app is not starting with the same error as above.

Comment: I fixed it by moving the main project to psycopg2 and SQLAlchemy 2.0 as well.

If you reply with your solution, I will choose it as the correct solution. Thanks @snakecharmerb

Answer (score -1):

if it is running on a mc environment then thats a kernal failure
but from guessing its a windows environment delete the i need you to delete  the current  psycopg global packages cause windows has a tendency to not run the  psycopg package i think its a bug  i had the same bug before

i hope this helps

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. This is on Windows with git bash.

But psycopg is a dependency of the project, wouldn't removing it have either no effect or cause the main app to malfunction?